# Solutions of a nonlinear transport equation

Tags: hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

Has the 'transport equation':
$$
\partial_t f+ \frac{x}{t}\partial_x f=0
$$
set on $(0,1)^2$ non constant solutions ?

If yes are there solutions satisfying $f(t,x)\leq x$ ?

Due to the origin of the problem, $x$ and $t$ appear to play similar roles.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you call this equation nonlinear? If $f,g$ satisfy your equation, then so does $\alpha f+\beta g$, for any $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: indeed it is linear, I was quite dumb at that time (might still be, beware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the characteristics are the lines passing by zero, we may hence have non-constant solutions by setting a non-constant profile on the opposite sides of the unit square. Doing so we lose the smoothness of f near (0,0). Do any of these solutions satisfy $f(t,x)\leq x$ ? yes, but only $f=0$.